# SQL injection in bwapp

Tags: sql, sql-injection

I've been trying to do a SQL Injection in BWAPP application level SQL Injection (GET/Search) 
while setting the security level to medium and high

here is a screenshot of the level:

[image: here is a screenshot of the level]

can anyone show me how to do an injection here..

Answer (score 0):

try parameter (-) and carry on to find your payload

Answer (score 0):

You should check the log.
In my case, the variables failed. My solution was to modify the file /var/www/html/bWAPP/sqli_1.php and add **msqli** on all lines containing *mysql*, and also changed the line: `$recordset = mysqli_query ($link, $sql);`

I hope it will help you